# What is the name for application/program button fonts?

Tags: windows, fonts, ide, android-studio

I want to change font size of the various context menu options ("File" ->,  "Window" -> etc) in Android Studio.

But when I try to google "increase font size in android studio" the search results refer to increasing font size in "Editor", but not of the program buttons/options themselves.

What is the technical name for program specific font size? I could use that technical name to get bette search results.

Comment: The options you are looking for are possibly part of the OS and not the program.

Comment: Applications usually use system fonts for things like menus and buttons. This provides a consistent look among applications and is highly recommended by Microsoft and others. Applications often provide for changing the font in an editor but for menus and buttons that is rare.